# How fast can you solve it?

Tags: number-sequence

Here's a quick and easy one:

What comes next in this sequence?

> 6 2 5 5 4 5 6 3 7 ?

Comment: http://www.creatievepuzzels.com/spel/speel1/puzzel53-2.htm

Comment: Ah, I did a cursory search of Puzzling.SE, but didn't look elsewhere. I suppose it is a pretty obvious sequence.

Comment: In retrospect, it would have been better to use number -> answer clues instead of a number sequence (e.g. 11 -> 4, 27 -> 8, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> 6

The explanation

> Each number in the sequence corresponds to the number of segments needed to display a digit on a calculator's screen.
>  `Digits:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>  `Sequence: 6 2 5 5 4 5 6 3 7 6`
>   |   The 1 here has 2 segemnts
>   |
>   |_| The 4 has 4 segments
>      |

Comment: Type on an old school calculator 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.  Then count the number of segments each number has...

Comment: Sure, I just need to figure out the formatting